# How to make get request from retrofit in Android?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I need to make a `Get` request from retrofit with parameter. URl:

```
http://www.something.com/search?param=hello+testing
```

This is my code:

```
 @GET("/search?param={tags}")
public Observable<List<Warehouse>> searchWithTags(@Query("tags") String tags);
```

I am using `Observable` from `rx-java` and tags is `Hello+testing`. Error I am getting :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: API.searchWithTags: URL query string "q={tags}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
```

What I am doing wrong here. I search for the exception on net but didn't find a good approach.

Comment: change `@GET("/search?param={tags}")` to `@GET("/search")`

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to express that is

```
@GET("/search")
public Observable<List<Warehouse>> searchWithTags(@Query("param") String tags);
```